# Replace all linebreaks with two whitespaces and revert it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to temporarily replace all linebreaks with two whitespaces and after some function on the string revert it back from two whitespaces to a linebreak.

But it doesn't work. It won't restore the linebreaks.

This is what I do:

1. First replace all duplicate whitespaces with a single one.

   ```
   $text = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ',$text );
   ```
2. Replace linebreaks with two whitespaces.

   ```
   $text = str_replace( array( '\r', '\r\n', '\n'), '  ', $text );
   ```
3. Run some functions..
4. Restore the linebreaks

   ```
   $text = str_replace( '  ', '\n', $text );
   ```

As far as I can see it replaces the linebreaks with a single whitespace. Not like defined two of them. What happens? Using `\s\s` doesn't change things.

---

Tested some things:

`str_replace` (step 2) fails to detect the linebreaks only AFTER I used `preg_replace` to replace duplicate whitespaces (step 1).

Without step 1 it works.

Comment: You're doing 4 different things here, and apparently one of them doesn't work? Which one? Please remove the other three from the question. Also please post the value of `$text` that is not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using those:

1. `$text = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $text);`

   This will replace only spaces. `\s` will match more than just spaces, because it also matches vertical whitespaces like linefeeds, carriage returns... and because of this, your second replace wasn't having any newlines to replace.
2. `$text = str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '  ', $text);`

   As hkpotter92 already pointed out, you need to use double quotes, otherwise, you are trying to match the literal characters instead of carriable returns and of line feeds.
3. `$text = str_replace('  ', "\n", $text);`

   Once again, you have to use double quotes here, otherwise, you would end up with the literal `\n` in place of the double spaces.

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/AcgF4M)

Comment: Your right. I've implemented it this way:

`while( strpos( $this->_text, '  ' ) ){
$this->_text = str_replace( '  ', ' ', $this->_text );
}`

Comment: @user2429266 That works too, if you don't mind using a loop :)

Comment: But there is another problem. This: `$text = str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), ' ', $text);` replaces every single linebreak twice. Not only once.

Comment: `$this->_text = str_replace( array( "\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '  <!linebreak>  ', $this->_text );` Makes this: "text LINEBREAK text LINEBREAK" to: "text   <!linebreak>    <!linebreak>   text   <!linebreak>    <!linebreak>  "

Comment: @user2429266 If I understand the problem well, that's because of the order. Try using this array instead: `array("\r\n", "\r", "\n")` That way, it will look for `\r\n` before `\r` and single replace breaks.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP considers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/1190388) `'\n'` to be literal `\n` string and not the newline character. You'd need to use double-quotes (`"`) for the job:

```
$text = str_replace( array( "\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '  ', $text );
```

Comment: Ok. My bad. But the problem is still there: preg_replace( '/\s+/', 'two whitespaces',$text ) replaces the new lines with a single whitespace instead of two whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

In regex `\s` means `whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")`. That's why it is changing your newlines. Use the space inside the character class `[ ]` for space only.

```
$text = preg_replace( '/[ ]+/', ' ',$text );
```

To change newlines into double spaces, use this one that uses double quotes.

```
$text = str_replace( array( "\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '  ', $text );
```

Or, you can use `preg_replace` for this one too.

```
$text = preg_replace( '/[\n\r]/', '  ',$text );
```